# Is there a measure for entanglement of $n$-qubit system?

Tags: entanglement

I am working on a topic related to an $n$-qubit system. I should obtain the entanglement.

As I searched, I could not find any measure to obtain the entanglement of a mixed $n$-qubit system.

Is there such a measure for that purpose?

Answer (score 2):

There are many measures of entanglement, such as

- [quantum discord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_discord)
- [partial positive transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peres%E2%80%93Horodecki_criterion)
- [positvity of coherent information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_information)
- [concurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrence_(quantum_computing)), and more.